# How to solve a "cannot unpack non-iterable Profile object" error?

Tags: python, django

I was making a project for my university assignment using django. I want to make a follower system using django, I wrote the code and am getting the following error

> cannot unpack non-iterable Profile object

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image=models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)
    description=models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='followed_by', blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def saveimg(self):
        super().save()

        img=Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height>300 or img.width>300:
            output_size=(300,300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.saveimg(self.image.path)
```

views.py

```
def follow_user(request, username):
    creator = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username__icontains=username)
    is_followed=False
    if request.user.profile.following.filter(creator).exists():
        request.user.profile.following.remove(creator)
        is_followed=False
    else:
        request.user.profile.add(following=creator)
        is_liked=True
    context={
        'creator':creator,
        'is_followed': request.user.profile.filter(following=creator).exists(),
        }
    return HttpResponseRedirect(home)
```

urls.py

```
path('user/<str:username>/follow', views.follow_user,name='follow_user'),
```

Traceback

Traceback:

> File "C:\Users\Mustafa
>   Lakhani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "C:\Users\Mustafa
>   Lakhani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "C:\Users\Mustafa
>   Lakhani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "D:\sb\blog\views.py" in follow_user
>     186.    if request.user.profile.following.filter(creator).exists():
>
> File "C:\Users\Mustafa
>   Lakhani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py"
>   in manager_method
>     82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Mustafa
>   Lakhani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py"
>   in filter
>     844.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Mustafa
>   Lakhani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py"
>   in _filter_or_exclude
>     862.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
>
> File "C:\Users\Mustafa
>   Lakhani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py"
>   in add_q
>     1263.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
>
> File "C:\Users\Mustafa
>   Lakhani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py"
>   in _add_q
>     1287.                     split_subq=split_subq,
>
> File "C:\Users\Mustafa
>   Lakhani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py"
>   in build_filter
>     1161.         arg, value = filter_expr
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /user/mustafalakhani/follow Exception
>   Value: cannot unpack non-iterable Profile object

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: @KlausD. added it

Comment: The `filter()` method usually expects keyword arguments, where the keyword is a field or similar. Maybe you wanted something like `filter(user=creator)`?